# how to list all the projects of a specific workspace of a specific user in asana api

Tags: api, asana

I need to select a user and then list all the projects that the user is working on. Also how can this be done with a specific workspace of the user? What would the url look like?

Also how do we access the teams that are created in asana using the asana api?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/) is decent.

Most notably, you're probably looking for endpoints `/users`, `/projects`, and `/projects/[project-id]/tasks`. To the best of my knowledge the API provides no way list all the projects a user is working on. You have to create that list yourself by iterating through all the tasks on a project.